# AWS ec2 Nginx + Django server easily gets to 100% CPU utilisation without much traffic

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx, gunicorn, nginx-config

Hi I am using AWS EC2 instance (c5.18xlarge (72vcpu and 144 Gib ram)) with Nginx + Django and postgresql.
The problem is it gets to 100% CPU utilisation in 400-500 concurrent users and slows down.
Here are my settings:

postgresql.conf

```
max_connections = 800
shared_buffers = 50000MB
```

Nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 128;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
worker_rlimit_nofile 50000;
events {
        worker_connections 10000;
        #multi_accept on; 
}
```

sysctl.conf

```
net.core.somaxconn = 65000
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 65535
fs.file-max = 90000
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
kernel.shmmax=1006632960
```

gunicorn_start.bash

NAME="django_app"                                   # Name of the application

```
DJANGODIR=/home/ubuntu/project              # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/home/ubuntu/env/run/gunicorn.sock  # we will communicte using this unix socket
USER=ubuntu                                         # the user to run as
GROUP=ubuntu                                        # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=128                                      # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spaw
TIMEOUT=120
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings      # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=project.wsgi              # WSGI module name
echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"
```

I know the server can't overload on the current usage of the app. Please suggest how can this be solved. Or how can it be debugged to reach the problem.

I am also attaching the top screenshot:
[image]

Comment: You have to figure out what uses the CPU time and why. That is called "profiling".

Comment: using "top" what process is using all the CPU?

Comment: @Trent I have attached the screen shot.

Comment: Without knowing what the endpoints are doing (CPU activities) - will be hard to debug remotely. Given the power of that server, there is no way 400-500 concurrent users should make a dent on resources, unless you have a bug in the code somewhere which causes an infinite loop, or does something daft causing the CPU to get smashed.